# Hash for install tool password is not constant

Tags: typo3

I'm facing a weird problem with he Install Tool Password of Typo3 6.2.6

The password that I thought to be it, is not valid any more.
So I tried to change it, but it didn't work.
The strange thing is, always when I anter the new password in the input field to let TYPO3 calculate a new hash for me, I get a different hash.

Is there anything in the LocalConfiguration.php file that could tell TYPO3 to create salt words on the fly or something like that?

I can login to the TYPO3 backend without any problems.

The saltedpassword configuration is like this (serialized string with manual line breaks by me)

```
a:2:{
  s:3:"BE.";
  a:4:{
    a:2: {
      s:3:"BE.";
      a:4:{
        s:21:"saltedPWHashingMethod";
        s:41:"TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\Salt\\PhpassSalt";
        s:11:"forceSalted";
        i:0;
        s:15:"onlyAuthService";
        i:0;
        s:12:"updatePasswd";
        i:1;
      }
      s:3:"FE.";
      a:5:{
        s:7:"enabled";
        i:1;
        s:21:"saltedPWHashingMethod";
        s:41:"TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\Salt\\PhpassSalt";
        s:11:"forceSalted";
        i:0;
        s:15:"onlyAuthService";
        i:0;
        s:12:"updatePasswd";
        i:1;
      }
    }
    s:21:"saltedPWHashingMethod";
    s:41:"TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\Salt\\PhpassSalt";
    s:11:"forceSalted";
    i:0;
    s:15:"onlyAuthService";
    i:0;
    s:12:"updatePasswd";
    i:1;
  }
  s:3:"FE.";
  a:5:{
    s:7:"enabled";
    i:1;
    s:21:"saltedPWHashingMethod";
    s:41:"TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\Salt\\PhpassSalt";
    s:11:"forceSalted";
    i:0;
    s:15:"onlyAuthService";
    i:0;
    s:12:"updatePasswd";
    i:1;
  }
}
```

My best guess is that it has to do something with file permissions. As I cannot see any place in the LocalConfiguration.php where I set my salt manually and by tracing the salt used in in typo3/sysext/saltedpasswords/Classes/Sal/PhpassSallt.php, I see that it is newly generated every time.

So where does TYPO3 store the generated salt phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mended it,

the problem was, that I couldn't save the `LocalConfiguration.php` file because of file permission issues.

Answer (score 2):

The salt is stored in the same string containing the password hash, using PHPs [`crypt()`-function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.crypt.php). The hash string is divided into parts by the character `$`. The first part tells the used hashing algorithm, the meaning of the other parts depends on the first part.

Example:

```
echo crypt('test');
```

prints `$1$cr6nr8HA$tY7hBRMQdxgeNWCQ6WmOt/`, which is stored in `LocalConfiguration.php` (at least for the install tool). This string consists of three parts, separated by the character `$`:

1. 1
2. cr6nr8HA
3. tY7hBRMQdxgeNWCQ6WmOt/

The first one is the used algorithm, the second and third one are the salt and the hash. The password can be checked by checking that `crypt($enteredPassword, $hashedPassword) === $hashedPassword`, because the `$hashedPassword` contains all needed info.

Comment: I know about the encryped hash string. But there is a salt string, that is added to the password before hashing. And this salt string is generated every time in my case. But it should be a constant string to work properly. And that must be stored somewhere. But where? And I think crypr is not sed in PhpassSalt.php but multiple runs of md5.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: that is not the question.

Comment: The used algorithm is defined by PhpassSalt.php. So the first part is `P` there is only a second part and no third, because the salt is applied before the crypt and not after (wouldn't make much sense the other way round). But what if I get a different crypted string every time I call it?

Comment: It's still stored the way I described above, but the delimiter between second and third part is not a `$`. This can be done since the salt has a known fixed length. And the salt is of course applied before hashing, but it is appended to the resulting hash at the end, in order to store it. You can see that in line 153 of PhphassSalt.php, in TYPO3 6.2.6

Comment: What about line 160 of the same file? First concatenation of salt and password, second the hash function

Comment: Yes, that's the hashing. And after the password is hashed repeatedly (always first concatenating salt, then hashing), in line 164 the salt is prepended to the hash (`$setting` = algorithm concatenated with) salt.

Comment: Thx for the help and great effort. I understood now that the salt string does not need to be saved anywhere. My issue was a different thing, see my own answer.